# Cannot access C# COM library

Tags: c#, web-services, com

I am building a COM class library with .NET 4 framework for FoxPro. Main code for library is quite small:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("054fbf26-6d37-4d84-a732-fc49d77eeb21")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IFingerPrintEvents
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void OnFinger(int id);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("7d07c9f9-a852-4287-9d7c-f5a9a6bdcf7b")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IFingerPrintDll
{
    [DispId(1)]
    string StartEnrollment();
    [DispId(2)]
    string Open(string connstring);
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IFingerPrintEvents))]
[Guid("D9755E64-49A5-44ED-971F-64621DBEEEDF")]
[ProgId("FingerPrint.dll")]
public class FingerPrintDll : ServicedComponent, IFingerPrintDll
{
...(Implements IFingerPrintDll and events from IFingerPrintEvents)...
}
```

I build everything in x86, set COM visible true in assembly info and signed the library. I can register it with RegAsm with /tlb and /codebase tags but when I try to use it in FoxPro with CREATEOBJECT() it says "Unknown COM status Code. OLE Error 0x80004003". When I try to add it to C# app (to test) and try to initiate with GetTypeFromProgID and then Activator.CreateInstance it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". Same is said when I try to add COM library through references. It shows no errors in code, but when I launch it shows same error.
I did COM library on C# once and it works both in foxpro and C#, but main difference now is that my library uses web service through service reference. Maybe there is a problem there? All responses appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Okey, my bad, I had null reference exception in my constructor because of using uninitialised object... Stupidity level 9000

Comment: So you suspect the problem is because of some new factor. What if you exclude that factor - remove the dependency on the service and retry? That will at least help you isolate the problem.

Comment: I removed all service references (even from app.config) but it didn't help. In the test app it looks like the type is created from Prog ID, but the Activator cannot create instance for it.

Comment: use this link buddy...http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/612604/Best-Practice-in-Writing-a-COM-Visible-Assembly-Cs